# matchesQuery function in Parse

Tags: node.js, parse-platform

I was wondering how can I solve a bug when I use matchesQuery function in Parse
here is my work example:

```
var MediaFile = Parse.Object.extend("MediaFile");
var Sport = Parse.Object.extend("Sport");
var Tag = Parse.Object.extend("Tag");

var testMedia = new Parse.Query(MediaFile);
var testInner = new Parse.Query(Sport);
var testInnerTag = new Parse.Query(Tag);

//testInner.exists("seachable");

user = Parse.User.current();
var relation = user.relation("sports");
var relationQ = relation.query();

testMedia.matchesQuery("sport", relationQ);
testMedia.find({
success: function(medias) {
// comments now contains the comments for posts with images.
console.log(medias);
response.success('success');
},
error: function(error) {
// comments now contains the comments for posts with images.
console.log(error);
response.error(error);
}
});
```

sometimes, it has executed without bug.
but most of times, it was happen such error:

{"code":102,"message":"wrong type of relation.  Expecting: Sport, but recieved: _User"}

and also for tags relation, following error was happen

{"code":102,"message":"bad type for $inQuery"}

I was tired to solve this problem with so much trying
anywhere I could not find reference how can solve such problem
it would be appreciate if anyone can helps me for solving out these problems

thank you in advance

Comment: Anyone?? I am trying to decide if this is a code issue on my side or it Parse changed something. All was working well and fine, until this past week. (Then it stopped working as normal)

Comment: Same problem. I think .query() on relation does not return a Parse.query type. But I dont have a solution for this at the moment.